# How to make round number. Power issues

Tags: c++, math

I have 2 math arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float a, b, x, f;
    printf("\nx=");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    a = 1/(12*pow(x,2) + 7*x-5);
    printf("\na=%.3f", a);
    b = pow(x,2)*pow(x,3);
    b=fabs(b);
    printf("\nb=%.3f", b);
    if (a + b <= 10)    
        if (2*pow(b,2) > 0 && 4*pow(a,2) > 0.00001) {
            f = 4*pow(a,2)-2*pow(b,4);
            printf("\nf1=%.3f", f);
        }
        else  {
            printf("\ x is worng (f1)");
            return 2;
        }
    else
        if (b!=0) {
            f = a/b;
            printf("\nf2=%.3", f);
        }
        else  {
            printf("\ x is wrong (f2)");
            return 3;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Some times the result of "f" is smaller than 0.001. I must use `printf("\nf2=%.3", f);` so that only 3 numbers are shown after dot. I want to make it seen without changing the result. In me head i thought of multiplying it by 10^(-n). But i can't think of a way. If there is some other ideas would be great.

Comment: Your words don't make sense in the sentences they are used in.  Please slow down and try again.  Also, you'll need to post the full code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to round numbers to only three decimal places, or something else? What do you want to print with the number 0.000125?

Comment: 0.001*10^(-1) or higher like 0.012*10^(-2).

Comment: Your second to last printf format string is broken, you are missing an f after %.3. To use scientific notation with printf you use %e, printf("%.3e", 0.000125);

Comment: Look up the %g specifier. It's like %f but more human-friendly.

Answer (score 4):

`std::scientific` is just for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::scientific << f;
```

Comment: Thanks gonna try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Your second to last printf is broken:

```
printf("\nf2=%.3", f);

test.c:3:20: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]
             printf("\nf2=%.3", f);
                    ^
test.c:3:20: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

An example on the use of printf:

```
printf("%.3f", 1.121212); // prints 1.121
```

To use scientific notation with printf you use %e

```
printf("%.3e", 0.000125); // prints 1.250e-04
```

Comment: Thats not what he asked for

Comment: @Treycos Yes, he wants to use printf in C++, but the format string is wrong. Go and run a printf() call with the format string from the question, "\nf2=%.3", it will give you bullshit because it is an invalid format.

Comment: 20.3k or not, the answer above gives exaclty what OP asked for, he's showing printf but not saying that he MUST use it

Comment: No, OP wants to shift the notation. `0.000324` would return `0.000` which is what OP doesn't want. OP wants to shift the "visible"numbers to the left and return `3.240`.

Comment: The question was far from clear. But the printf format string is still wrong, which was the original piece of code pasted.